# Use Ebooks or normal books?

Tags: environmental-impact, carbon-footprint

Ebooks and normal paper books both contribute to environmental damage in some way.

I want to know, **which of those two contributes to less environmental damage, on average?**

Comment: @LShaver sorry. should I delete this question?

Comment: It depends... does that one answer *your* question? Or is your question somehow different? If so, you'd need to provide more detail here.

Comment: @LShaver I think I have got the answer.

Comment: Then in that case, I'd mark the question as a duplicate, which you should be able to do by clicking "flag" beneath the post.